# JSON PHP to JSON Python

Tags: php, python, json

I am converting my php over to python.

In my php I have (this has always work with my iPhone app):

```
...
$profile = mysql_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$profile_json = array();
$profile_json[] = $profile;
echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'myProfile' => $profile_json));
```

I know have this in Python (doesn't seem to work with iPhone app):

```
...
profile = db_cursor.fetchone()
json_user_profile = json.dumps(profile)
json_obj= {'success': 1, 'myProfile': json_user_profile,}
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(json_obj))
```

I need my python to return exactly what my php was returning.

Anyone up to help? :)

Comment: What was your PHP returning? What is your Python code doing differently? What are the values that come back from the database? Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the rest of the help to find out how to ask a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need to change it to:

```
profile = db_cursor.fetchone()
json_obj= {'success': 1, 'myProfile': profile}
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(json_obj))
```

Otherwise you are double json encoding the profile

Comment: This works in another python file where I am using fetchall(). That returns a tuple of dictionaries. fetchone() seem to be just returning a dictionary. I think I need to convert this one dictionary to a tuple containing the dictionary. I am very new to python.